# Android's JNI failed to load dependency library

Tags: android, java-native-interface

My android app uses JNI to call to a C++ lib. The C++ lib is successfully built, but when run in virtual device the app crash with the following error: `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "libwpa_client.so". File not found.`

What happens here? My dev environment is Windows 64 bits & eclipse Luna.

**UPDATE**

This is crash log when the app run under Genymotion:

---

```
05-13 03:37:19.417: E/art(2280): dlopen("/data/app/com.sample.operator/lib/x86/libAndroidJNI.so", RTLD_LAZY) failed: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "_ZN7android16ScreenshotClient6updateERKNS_2spINS_7IBinderEEE" referenced by "libAndroidJNI.so"...
05-13 03:37:19.418: D/AndroidRuntime(2280): Shutting down VM
05-13 03:37:19.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2280): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-13 03:37:19.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2280): Process: com.example.operator, PID: 2280
05-13 03:37:19.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2280): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "_ZN7android16ScreenshotClient6updateERKNS_2spINS_7IBinderEEE" referenced by "libAndroidJNI.so"...
05-13 03:37:19.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2280):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:371)
05-13 03:37:19.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2280):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:988)
05-13 03:37:19.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2280):     at ...
05-13 03:37:19.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2280):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
05-13 03:37:19.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2280):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1606)
05-13 03:37:19.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2280):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2743)
05-13 03:37:19.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2280):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:151)
05-13 03:37:19.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2280):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1386)
05-13 03:37:19.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2280):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-13 03:37:19.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2280):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
05-13 03:37:19.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2280):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
05-13 03:37:19.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2280):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-13 03:37:19.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2280):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
05-13 03:37:19.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2280):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
05-13 03:37:19.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2280):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: Have you included the correct version (ARM, ARMv7, x86) of your library in your project and in the correct folder?

Comment: Yes, I built both x86 & armeabi package & put them to correct folder already.

Comment: You can use [inotifytools for Android](https://github.com/mkttanabe/inotifywait-for-Android) to see what files your app tries to load.

Comment: my app call to native lib named: libAndroidJNI.so, this lib in turn call some functions in libwpa_client.so. But libwpa_client.so has failed to load due to file not found error.

Comment: As I wrote use intotfytools because you know the filename but not the exact path your app tries to load. Look at the intotify output and compare it with the files that really exist in the file-system.

Comment: In Android.mk, I had defined LOCAL_LDLIBS that pointed to $(LOCAL_PATH)/system4/libwpa_client.so & the lib is already there. So I don't think my lib have no idea where to load dependency lib.

Answer (score 0):

Have you loaded the library in your application By using System.loadlibrary(yourlobraryname)?and also check it should available in your application lib folder.

Comment: Yes, but the lib is failed to load because of libwpa_client.so cannot be loaded.

Comment: have you compiled your library using android JNI tool

Comment: Yes, the lib has been built using android jni tool.

Comment: would you share the crashed log  for reference